# How to replace multiple occurrences of a character with a string with a random ASCII character?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program that replaces the spaces in between inputted words with random ASCII punctuation.

I have tried using the string and random module to the best of my ability, but have had no luck so far.

```py
    def basewords():
        print("Enter base words here:")
        q = str(input("TIP: Enter your desired words seperated by spaces only.\n> "))
        lst = [string.punctuation, string.digits]
        x = ''.join(random.choice(lst)(c) for c in q)
        q = q.replace(" ", x)
        print(q)
```

I want the spaces in between words (e.g. Hello World Dog House) with randomized ASCII punctuation characters so that it could theoretically end up like "Hello!World^Dog,House". However, currently, I am getting a TypeError. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think using random.choice(lst[0]) might be a step in the right direction.

Comment: Your typeerror is on the line with `x = ...`. Can you say a bit about what you want that line to do? Sometimes when you get a runtime error, it can help to start by confirming the line with the error does what you think it does.

Comment: Well, I would like that specific line to randomly generate some ASCII punctuation to then replace the inputted string with. This code was just what I am currently toying around with, so I am completely open to changes and input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just join the two lists of special characters, don't put them in a list for `random.choice`. One liner example:

```
''.join(i if i != ' ' else random.choice(string.punctuation + string.digits)
    for i in q)
```

You can of course...

```
result = ''
for i in q:
    if i != ' ':
        result += i
    else:
        result += random.choice(string.punctuation + string.digits)
q = result
```

The second example is the verbose version of the one-liner example above.
To understand it you can split it in peaces.

```
q = ''.join( LIST_COMPREHANSION )
```

This joins with empty strings the LIST_COMPREHANSION inside. You can check https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python for details. It consists of:

```
EXPRESSION for i in q
```

The expression itself isa ternary operator - https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html:

```
i if i != ' ' else random.choice(string.punctuation + string.digits)
```

However using str.replace will not work, the second argument is constant and you can not use random character generator there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Doncho Gunchev! However, could you perhaps explain how the one-liner code works?

Comment: Done, changed the code to use a ternary operator instead of arithmetic tricks.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your `TypeError` is because of this line:

`x = ''.join(random.choice(lst)(c) for c in q)`

`random.choice(iterable)` returns one random item in `iterable`, since your iterable is composed of strings, it returns a string. When doing this `(c)` you are trying to call a string like a function, this raises a `TypeError` because a string is not callable.

How about something like this instead:

```
def basewords():
    print("Enter base words here:")
    q = str(input("TIP: Enter your desired words seperated by spaces only.\n> "))
    specialchars = string.punctuation + string.digits
    def rand():
        return random.choice(specialchars)
    print(''.join(x.replace(' ', rand()) for x in q))
```

Demo:

```
In [41]: basewords()
Enter base words here:
TIP: Enter your desired words seperated by spaces only.
> Hello World Dog House
Hello;World>Dog3House
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont you think generating random numbers between the ascii value of the first punctuation (33) and the last punctuation (47), will be more easier to implement. And then u can just use it in you code as usual, by using its ascii value to find the corresponding character.

You can more about the ascii table [here:](https://theasciicode.com.ar/)

<-Hope it simplifies your solution.

<-UpVote If HelpFul